# Residue method and order of poles

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to use the residue method for the formula $(1-e^{-sT})/s^3$.
At the start I thought that the order of the pole $s=0$ is $3$ but then I saw that $(1-e^{-sT})/s$ at $s=0$ is $T$. so does that mean that the order of the pole will be $2$?
Thanks.
will the answer change if the function is multiplied by  $1/(1-e^{Ts}Z^{-1})$ which doesn't have poles?
I'm not trying to turn it into a series I'm trying to use the formula for poles but wasn't sure what is the pole order

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\exp(-sT)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-sT)^k}{k!}$$

Comment: do you mean that the residue is 1? ( The factor of $1/s$?

Comment: well you have $$(1- (1-sT+\frac{(sT)^2}{2}-\frac{(sT)^3}{3!}\pm \dots))
 \cdot s^{-3}$$

Comment: o.k so the residue of the whole function is $T^2/2$?

Comment: will the answer change if the function is multiplied by  $1/(1-e^{Ts}Z^{-1}$ which doesn't have poles?